# How to remove days in FSCalendar Swift library

Tags: swift, fscalendar

i'm using FSCalendar and want to remove days (Sun, mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, and Sat) from calendar

[image]

for now i only change the color to clear

```
calendarView.appearance.weekdayTextColor = UIColor.clear
```

Comment: Can you share the link for the library ?

Comment: here https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45261579/how-to-compare-json-api-dates-with-fscalendar-and-display-events-in-tableview have you done this type or can u help me to do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can hide/remvove days from calendar using `calendarWeekdayView`.

**Hide**

```
calendarView.calendarWeekdayView.isHidden = true
```

**Remove**

```
calendarView.calendarWeekdayView.removeFromSuperview()
```

Comment: Great Thanks! But if you but if you don't mind, can i ask one more thing? How to change the month text color?

Comment: @ArielGemilang calendarView.appearance.headerTitleColor = UIColor.red

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45261579/how-to-compare-json-api-dates-with-fscalendar-and-display-events-in-tableview can u help me

Answer (score 2):

This library contains the property to handle this condition

self.calendar.weekdayHeight = 0

and this will remove the days header.