# Date Format Error in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am new to the swift library.
I am using the calendar in swift and I want to show the events in calendar. The events are obtained from the Json API but when I compare the date it is showing an error.

This is the code

```
  let data = event["date"] as? String
  let newString = data?.replacingOccurrences(of: "/", with: "-")
  self.FirstData = self.EventDates[0]
```

compare function

```
 func compareDate(date : String){
        let date = date

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
      ====>>>>Error in line 
  let dateFromString : NSDate = dateFormatter.date(from: date)! as NSDate 
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        let datenew = dateFormatter.string(from: dateFromString as Date)
        print("datee",datenew)

    }
```

**Error:** fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

How to compare date or resolve this issue.

Comment: In which format you received date from api.

Comment: Check the date which you are passing in `compareDate`. It should be of format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`

Comment: Why the casting to `NSDate`? And either your dateformat is wrong or you need to set up the `Locale` of the `DateFormatter`.

Comment: @MinuMaster dateString "11-23-2016"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to compare date in swift 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294529/how-to-compare-date-in-swift-3-0)

Comment: `"11-23-2016"` clearly is not formatted as `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`, therefore date formatter returns `nil`, and when you force unwrap it with `!` you get a crash.

Comment: Why do you convert the string with `replacingOccurrencesOf`? `DateFormatter` can handle slashes, too. And do not use `NSDate` in Swift 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app is crashing because of date string was not in the same format which was assigned to `dateformatter`. Because of that date object return nil value.

And you force `nil` value to convert `NSDate` object. Because of that app is crashing.

You just need to change your compare date method as below:

```
func compareDate(date : String) -> Date? {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
    let dateFromString = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
    print("datee", dateFromString ?? "")
    return dateFromString
}
```

By doing this you can able to create the `Date` object.

Comment: @Dhruv try this code it will work for creating date object as you received date in "11-23-2016" format.

Comment: Why did you kept those `Date -> NSDate -> Date` nonsense casting? Just get rid of it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45261579/how-to-compare-json-api-dates-with-fscalendar-and-display-events-in-tableview?rq=1 am trying to do like this

Answer (score 2):

try this :-

```
func convertDate(date:String) -> String {
     let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    let tempLocale = dateFormatter.locale // save locale temporarily
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") 
   // date format getting from server 
     dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'"

    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: date)!
    //date format you want
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    dateFormatter.locale = tempLocale // reset the locale
    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    print("EXACT_DATE : \(dateString)")
    return dateString
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`date(from:)` returns an optional `Date` simply because it may fail to properly convert the given string. As you cannot be sure when this happens you must not force unwrap the result (`dateFormatter.date(from: date)!`) but rather safely unwrap the optional, i. e. using this construct:

```
if let dateFromString: NSDate = dateFormatter.date(from: date) as NSDate {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this to change date format

```
 let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
 dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "GMT")
 let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2012-12-06 T 06:00:00 ")

 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
 let goodDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date!)
```

Comment: bro I can run this code     let goodDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date!) getting error

Comment: Why use `Foundation` classes when they have native Swift equivalents (`DateFormatter` and `TimeZone`)?