# How to remove all weekends in FSCalendar

Tags: ios, swift, fscalendar

I would like to remove all weekends from my **FSCalendar** to show only weekdays. Thank you in advance. So far I manage that I can't pick weekend days from calendar. I would like to that weekends do not show at all

```
  func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, shouldSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) -> Bool {
        return CheckSatSunday(today: date)
    }
```

Disable picking weekedn on calendar

```
    func CheckSatSunday(today:Date) ->Bool{

        var DayExist:Bool
        // let today = NSDate()

        let calendar =
            NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier:NSCalendar.Identifier.gregorian)
        let components = calendar!.components([.weekday], from: today)

        if components.weekday == 1 {
            print("Sunday")
            DayExist = false
        } else if components.weekday == 7{
            print("Saturday")

            DayExist = false
        } else{
            print("It's not Saturday and  Sunday ")
            DayExist = true
        }
        print("weekday :\(String(describing: components.weekday)) ")
        return DayExist
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Without showing at least some (research) effort, you're highly unlikely to receive an answer.

Comment: @mindelicious FSCalendar have multiple calendar types. on which calendar are you working ?

Comment: @NiravKotecha oh i didn't know. Working on calendar from: [Github]:[https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar].

Comment: @DávidPásztor so far I manage that I can't pick weekend days from calendar. I will edit my question and add code. I would like to that weekends do not show at all

Answer (score 0):

Found this other question about it, but here they refer to weekdays

[How to remove days in FSCalendar Swift library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42994617/how-to-remove-days-in-fscalendar-swift-library)

I haven't use the library personally, but I assume that if there is a public weekdays property it should be weekends as well, or at least with this you can figure out a logic to remove days selectively

Comment: Unfortunately, It removes the names of the days: Mon, Tue, etc.